# crond service running after removing the entry in crontab

Tags: linux, centos7, cron, incrontab, incrond

I removed the entries in crontab for root and still, I can see the scripts running tail -f /var/log/cron.

How can I remove those entries.

Output of cron log:

CROND[2736]: (root) CMD (/home/centos/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-avail --mem-used --swap-util --swap-used --from-cron)

Nov 26 06:57:01 CROND[2738]: (root) CMD (/opt/aws-scripts-mon/jvm_stat.sh)

Comment: In addition to a personal crontab (`crontab -e`) there are also  the system crontab `/etc/crontab`,  files in `/etc/cron.d/` with a cron snippet 
or an executable (script) in the a `/etc/cron.[hourly |daily |weekly |monthly]` directory as possible places for root to schedule jobs....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing a crontab file, and saving it, verify that the system log says something like :

> "crontab.yciBZ6/crontab" 24L, 1887C written
>   crontab: installing new crontab

If not, just restart crond using `sudo systemctl reload crond.service`

And if you have processes already running started by cron, you might need to kill them as well.